# GitHub: SSH over HTTPS for third party app

Tags: authentication, github

I am a hardware guy first and software second so GitHub is not my forte.

I had Altium Designer setup with my GitHub server for version control. When GitHub forced 2FA recently it broke the link to Altium which, unfortunately doesn't have stellar GitHub integration.

There are 6 fields I am allowed to enter in Altium to point it to my (GitHub) server:
1.) Method (HTTP, HTTPS, file, svn)
2.) Server (URL)
3.) Port
4.) Repo Subfolder
5.) username
6.) Password

Again, nothing changed except moving to 2FA. Now, when I attempt to login it obviously says it could not connect to the server because Altium has no provisions to provide a token during the login process.

I read the article at GitHub here: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

But I have no idea if that will do anything for me. Is there a way to route my Altium server connection to use my SSH key outside of the Altium environment? Or perhaps another way to "whitelist" my desktop in GitHub for SSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub has not forced 2FA on for users.  That wouldn't be useful, because people could just not set up a second factor.  It's possible your organization has required this, though.

However, GitHub is deprecating the use of a plain password when using Git over HTTPS in favor of a token.  Using a plain password was already forbidden for users who use 2FA, since there's no place to send a 2FA code (and for automated systems, doing that would be very inconvenient).

In this case, it's easy to keep using HTTPS: just generate a personal access token  (in the developer settings) with the `repo` scope and paste it into the password field.  Git doesn't know the difference between a password and a token; they're both the same to it.  This also has a bunch of other benefits:

- If you change your password, the token isn't automatically cleaned up, so you don't have to change Altium Designer.
- If you decide you want to revoke that token, you can do so independently of changing your password.

If you're using SSO, you need to enable that token for SSO using the drop-down before it can be used to access protected resources.